# Perform multiple ajax requests in background in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I have a situation where i need to hit multiple ajax requests via chrome extension and show the success as result in popup html of chrome extension.

I will loop the list of url(s) in array and perform in ajax requests. This works well until my chrome extension is open. But as soon as i click outside or change the tab, the extension gets closed and the script is terminated.

I have a button in my extension. When i click on it, i need to hit all the ajax in background and when i will open the extension(no matter how many times), it has to show how many requests are completed(basically the success result from ajax).

Can some one help me out with it.

Comment: It's described in [extension overview: architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch): use a background/event page and [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging). If you're lucky someone will provide a detailed example.

Comment: @wOxxOm He's lucky today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Popup window, by design, is destroyed (and not hidden) every time it loses focus, which leads to script termination.

On the other hand, background pages (and to some extent, event pages) are designed to be "always there" and do lengthy processing or always-on event handling.

So, you need both: a background page to do the processing and the popup to display the UI.

The idea is as follows:

- The background page has a message listener that can:

  - Initiate AJAX processing
  - Return the current progress by request
- The background page emits a message every time the progress changes
- The popup page, when opened, requests current progress from the background
- After that, as long as it's opened, it listens to progress messages from the background.

Something like this:

```
+--------------+   message: request   +--------------+    time
|  Background  |       progress       |    Popup     |      |
|     page     | <------------------- |    window    |     \|/
|              |   respond: stopped   |              |
|              | -------------------> | (  display ) |
|              |                      | (   start  ) |
|              |                      | (  button  ) |
|              |                      |              |
|              |       message:       |              |
|              |      start AJAX      | (   user   ) |
|  ( starts )  | <------------------- | (  clicks  ) |
|  (  AJAX  )  |                      |              |
|              |                      |              |
      ...                                   ...
|              |                      |              |
|  (  some  )  |       message:       |              |
|  (  AJAX  )  |     progress N/M     | (  update  ) |
|  (  done  )  | -------------------> | ( progress ) |
|              |                      | (   N/M    ) |
|              |                      +--------------+
|              |                        (  popup   )
|  (  some  )  |       message:         (  closes  )
|  (  AJAX  )  |    progress N+1/M    
|  (  done  )  | ------ ???          (nothing listens)
|              |
|              |   message: request   +--------------+
|  Background  |       progress       |    Popup     |
|     page     | <------------------- |    window    |
|              |   respond: N+1/M     |              |
|              | -------------------> | (  display ) |
|              |                      | (  progress) |
|              |                      | (   N+1/M  ) |   
|  (  some  )  |       message:       |              |
|  (  AJAX  )  |    progress N+2/M    | (  update  ) |
|  (  done  )  | -------------------> | ( progress ) |  
|              |                      | (   N+2/M  ) |
      ...                                    ...
```

Example implementation of the background page:

```
var done = 0;
var total = 0;
var processing = false;

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  switch (message.type) {
    case "queryProgress":
      sendResponse({
        processing: processing,
        total: total,
        done: done
      });
      break;
    case "startProcessing":     // Assumes the list of AJAX to process
      doAllAJAX(message.list);  //   is passed in the message
      break;
  }
});

function doAllAJAX(list) {
  total = list.length;
  done = 0;
  processing = true;
  /* Initiate AJAX processing here for the list with onAJAXSuccess as a callback */
}

function onAJAXSuccess() {
  done++;
  if (done == total) { processing = false; }
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    type: "progressReport",
    processing: processing,
    total: total,
    done: done
  });
}
```

Implementation of the AJAX, error handling and the popup left as an exercise for the reader.